# how do I have a native browser function work with `await`?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a snippet of code which repeatedly checks if there's a pop-up confirm box. If a pop-up confirm box appears, the code let the confirm box stay for 2 seconds and automatically clicks on the cancel button.

Here are 2 snippets of JS code.

## snippet 1

The first one is the code I'm working.

```
function sleep() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
}

async function delayClick(element) {
  await sleep(); // Wait for 2 seconds
  element.click();
}

// Custom confirm function implementation
window.customConfirm = function (message) {
  console.log('Confirmation message:', message);
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const dialog = document.createElement('dialog');
    dialog.innerHTML = `
      <div>${message}</div>
      <button id="confirm-yes">Yes</button>
      <button id="confirm-no">No</button>
    `;
    document.body.appendChild(dialog);

    const confirmYes = dialog.querySelector('#confirm-yes');
    const confirmNo = dialog.querySelector('#confirm-no');

    confirmYes.addEventListener('click', () => {
      document.body.removeChild(dialog);
      resolve(true);
    });

    confirmNo.addEventListener('click', () => {
      document.body.removeChild(dialog);
      resolve(false);
    });
  });
};

// Override the confirm function with our custom implementation
const originalConfirm = window.confirm;
window.confirm = window.customConfirm;

// Function to set up the MutationObserver
async function setupObserver() {
  const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList) => {
    for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
      for (const node of mutation.addedNodes) {
        if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && node.tagName === 'DIALOG') {
          // Automatically click the "Cancel" button (No)
          const cancelButton = node.querySelector('#confirm-no');
          if (cancelButton) {
            delayClick(cancelButton);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  const config = {
    childList: true, // Observe direct children of the document.body for changes
    subtree: true, // Observe all descendants of the document.body for changes
  };

  observer.observe(document.body, config);
}
```

## snippet 2

the second snippet is used to render a pop-up confirm box

```
var userPreference;

if (confirm("Do you want to save changes?") == true) {
    userPreference = "Data saved successfully!";
} else {
    userPreference = "Save Cancelled!";
}
```

I ran the first snippet of code in Chrome's console inspector and then the second one. The confirm box did pop up and disappear, but only in logging text. However, the first snippet didn't let the confirm box stay for 2 seconds. How do I fix it?

Comment: One cannot replace `confirm` with a custom version, it is not possible to synchronously return a boolean.